# Can't save Apache httpd.conf file

Tags: django, apache-http-server

I'm trying to edit the httpd.conf file so I can use django on my Apache server, but I get an error message saying, "Please check if this file is opened in another program," when I try to save the changes.  The server is not running while I try to save.  I'm using The BitNami DjangoStack package.  Where else could this file be being used?

Comment: How are you trying to open the file? vim? notepad ++ ? And which OS ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using Windows stack. You can solve this by running your editor program as `Administrator`.

Please have a look at following related questions
1. [Unable to edit and save a file on remote machine using notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763067/unable-to-edit-and-save-a-file-on-remote-machine-using-notepad)
2. [Notepad++ “Check if file is open in another program” No other program open](https://superuser.com/questions/525214/notepad-check-if-file-is-open-in-another-program-no-other-program-open)

If using Linux, then you can open `httpd.conf` as `root user` or by using `sudo` command.

Answer (score 1):

That's the error message you get when you try to save in Notepad++ when you do not have permission to save it. (In Notepad, the message will be "You do not have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission."

You need to **right click the Notepad(++) application link** (the desktop icon or start menu item) **and choose "Run as administrator"**.